# UWP: How to fix focus on particular UI element so that i can receive key press events?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

So i have chat window with a text box, a mic button and some other buttons for settings and sharing. So i want to always switch on the mic whenever space button is pressed, except when the textbox has focus. No matter if other buttons are clicked last, space-bar should turn-on the mic.

Any help or pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working sample.

**Code Behind**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
    }

    private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Space && txtData.FocusState == FocusState.Unfocused))
        {
            txtData.Text = "Mike Called";
        }
    }
}
```

`txtData` here is my `TextBox` that I an checking if I have `FocusState` `Unfocused`

**XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App12.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App12"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBox Text="Hello World" Name="txtData" Width="300" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe the `KeyDown` event of `Window.Current.CoreWindow`. It will be fired everytime user press any key, regardless of focused control. Only your app has to be focused.

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;

private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Handled)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Your event handling
}
```